# Creating a DSNless connection to Pervasive in VBA

Tags: vba, pervasive, pervasive-sql

I'm very new at connecting to databases so I apologise if I'm not familiar with some of the terminology.

I would like to open up a DSNless connection to the pervasive database using VBA and I'm running into various issues. The forums that I have come across all give various bits of code which are helpful but I would like to see one full subroutine to see how it all fits together. By trying to apply different bits of code to my code I end up running into various error codes.

Therfore could someone please post an example of the full code to open a connection and create a recordset. It would be most appreciated

FROM COMMENTS

```
Sub pervasiveExample() 
Dim adoConn As ADODB.Connection 
Set adoConn = New ADODB.Connection 
adoConn.Provider = "PervasiveOLEDB" 
adoConn.ConnectionString = "driver={Pervasive ODBC Client Interface};Data Source=C:\TestData" 
adoConn.Open 
If adoConn.State = adStateOpen Then 
    MsgBox "Welcome" 
Else MsgBox "Error connecting to Database." 
End If 
End Sub
```

This is the error I then get: run-time error'-2147217837(80040e53)': Mode, Protection Level, or unknown parameter has been set (incorrectly) in the connection string

Comment: It is nearly always a good idea to post any examples that you have tried.

Comment: BTW, you are sure you have the right connections strings? http://www.connectionstrings.com/pervasive

Comment: Sub pervasiveExample()


Dim adoConn As ADODB.Connection
Set adoConn = New ADODB.Connection


adoConn.Provider = "PervasiveOLEDB"

adoConn.ConnectionString = "driver={Pervasive ODBC Client Interface};Data Source=C:\TestData"

adoConn.Open

If adoConn.State = adStateOpen Then
MsgBox "Welcome"
Else
MsgBox "Error connecting to Database."
End If

End Sub 

This is the error I then get:
run-time error'-2147217837(80040e53)': Mode, Protection Level, or unknown parameter has been set (incorrectly) in the connection string

Comment: The database is on my local server in a folder called TestData. I'm trying to connect to that database without having to set up a DSN name on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, I see your problem:

```
Sub pervasiveExample()
Dim adoConn As ADODB.Connection
Set adoConn = New ADODB.Connection
adoConn.ConnectionString = "driver={Pervasive ODBC Client Interface};DBQ=DEMODATA"
adoConn.Open
If adoConn.State = adStateOpen Then
    MsgBox "Welcome"
Else
    MsgBox "Error connecting to Database."
End If
End Sub
```

If you are using the "driver="  in the connection string, you cannot use a path.  You must specify the database name (or engine DSN by using ServerDSN= and ServerName= for remote connections) in the connection string.  You also do not specify a Provider when using the ODBC driver.

You cannot connect to a PSQL database without creating at least a Pervasive Database Name.  You don't need an ODBC DSN but it helps.  There is no supported way to connect to a path with PSQL ODBC or OLEDB.

You can create the Database Name in code though using DTO.